# PHP function called as array element to be replaced with function's return value

Tags: php

I first saw such behavior in Laravel in the documentation for [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#merging-conditional-attributes), where the `$this->mergeWhen()` functionality is described.

What I actually want to accomplish is call a function as an element in an array and set it's returned value as key => value pair in the array where it is called. Pretty basic, actually here is the code, it is quite self explanatory.

```
$data = ['name' => 'John', getSurname()];
print_r($data);


function getSurname()
{
    return ['surname' => 'Doe'];
}
```

This works fine but the returned value is like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [0] => Array
        (
            [surname] => Doe
        )

)
```

What would I like is the result to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [surname] => Doe
)
```

Comment: Why don't pass array into a function and merge into that?

Comment: Because the original array can be large array and I want to conditionally add a column (like middlename for example) only if the column exists somewhere else. To avoid passing the whole array to a function that will conditionally add only a single element, I went on with the approach recommended below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

This can be accomplished by using the `array_merge` PHP function to merge the existing and the returned array, like so:

```
$data = array_merge(['name' => 'John'], getSurname());
```

Why is this cool? Because the getSurname() function can have heavy logic inside. For example it can return the result as `['surname' => 'Doe']` or as `['middlename' => 'Mike', 'surname' => 'Doe']` depending on what data we have for the customer. Our array will work dynamically. We are abstracting the logic to the getSurname function which can be a class method as well.

In contrast, if not used this way, the only other solution I can imagine for the given scenario is the following:

```
$data = ['name' => 'John'];
if(//code checking if the user has surname) {
    $data['surname'] = 'Doe';
}
if(//code checking if the user has middlename) {
     $data['middlename'] = 'Mike';
}
```

I fancy the upper, more abstract solution.